# how to measure process cpu consumption?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel, solaris

I have a case in which a process is forked() in a heavy loaded system. I wish to know
if the process has started running (started consuming cpu). I have to monitor this child process cpu consumption from parent process.

Can you please suggest what are all the possible ways I can do this. I can check for pr_time
in prusage_t to get the cpu time used by child process but I am looking for more options.

Answer (score 4):

Please check this to get the cpu utilization.
https://github.com/fho/code_snippets/blob/master/c/getusage.c

You can get the child process id when you fork the process.So at parent process just check for the child process id.